# Parameters are not getting replaced in Anorm prepared query for embedded text queries

Tags: postgresql, scala, anorm

We have a use-case where we need to pivot the result set of a query to columns for insert statement. For that, we are using `crosstab` which takes text sql as a parameter.

so the query might conceptually look like this:

```
insert into table(col1, col2, ...)
select col1, col2, ...
from crosstab($$
  select ....
  where something = {something}
$$)
...
```

in postgresql client, it all works perfectly fine.

Now, when we are trying to implement this in code with Anorm, it would look as follows:

```
val sql = $"""
|insert into table(col1, col2, ...)
|select col1, col2, ...
|from crosstab($$$$
|  select ....
|  where something = {something}
|$$$$)
|...
"""

SQL(sql).on("something" -> param).execute()
```

This should work, but it does not. The reason is that in this particular case, parameters defined in the internal SQL string is not getting replaced with the actual value.

Of course, it is possible to build the SQL string by hand using string interpolation. But, I would prefer to use the tools that built for it.

What is there a way to make the parameters replacements work in this case?

Comment: Shouldn't this be `val sql = s""" ... ${something} ..."""`?

Comment: @mfirry As I mentioned, I am trying to avoid replacing the query by hand, and use anorm API instead

Comment: 1. Rather use Anorm interpolation. 2. Avoid `$$$$` as delimiter.

Comment: I see. So the `$"""...` comes from Anorm?

Comment: @cchantep for crosstab I must use the custom delimeter. And I do rather use Anorm interpolation, but in this case it does not work :)

Comment: @mfirry Nope, this is a regular string interpolation from scala.

Comment: There is nothing that make you have to use `$$` as cross table delimiter. `'` can be used (or whatever char that do not already have special meaning for Anorm or JDBC/SQL).